# How remove space on around content (css)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please view this example :

```css
html, body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #abebff;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.box {
    border: 1px red dotted;
}

#side-menu {
    background-color: #204d74;
    padding: 0px;
}

#side-menu h1 {
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.display-table {
    display: table;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}

.display-table-row {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
}

.display-table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    height: 100%;
}

.valign-top {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid display-table">
    <div class="row display-table-row">
        <!--Side Menu-->
        <div class="col-md-2 display-table-cell valign-top" id="side-menu">
            <h1>Navigation</h1>
        </div>
        <!--Content-->
        <div class="col-md-10 box display-table-cell valign-top">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="jquery/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

I try to create simple admin panel but can not understand how can remove free spaces around html page ?
I used padding or margin and other css elements but not fixed .
please help me .
Thank you .

Comment: Posting relevant code along with the question in this website is free.

Comment: Ohhh , Sory men , This is first time snippet i used .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code seems fine except you have not given a `width` to your `display-table` div. Change it like so:

```
.display-table {
    display: table;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%; //added
}
```

```css
html, body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #abebff;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.box {
    border: 1px red dotted;
}

#side-menu {
    background-color: #204d74;
    padding: 0px;
}

#side-menu h1 {
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.display-table {
    display: table;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%
}

.display-table-row {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
}

.display-table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
    height: 100%;
}

.valign-top {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid display-table">
    <div class="row display-table-row">
        <!--Side Menu-->
        <div class="col-md-2 display-table-cell valign-top" id="side-menu">
            <h1>Navigation</h1>
        </div>
        <!--Content-->
        <div class="col-md-10 box display-table-cell valign-top">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="jquery/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: @mah454 id it answer your question, please accept the answer so may it will help to other people.

Comment: Cheers ... Accept so it can help others as well